# How to check if an XML file has a minimum structure (Java)?

Tags: java, xml

I need to check if an XML file (which is represented as a String right now) has a minimum structure, which is also stored in another file/string.

A little example to explain what I mean is described in this image:

[image: this image]

The minimum structure is in the top-right frame.

```
Template = "<A><B/><C><E></E></C></A>"
XML1 = "<A><B/><C><D></D><E/><F/></A>" //Compliant to Template: the structure is kept
XML2 = "<A><B><E/></B><C/></A>" //Not compliant to Template: E is child of B here, while E is child of C in Template
XML3 = "<A><C><E/><D/></C><F></F><B/></A>" //Compliant to Template: the order of children doesn't matter
```

One possible approach is to transform the two XML files that I want to check in two trees and, for each node of the template, compare paths from the root of the tree, assuming names are unique. Are there any other ways or libraries I could use?

Comment: I haven't thought it out in detail but I might be tempted to consider an approach using  a combination of Sax and Dom. Load the minimum structure into a DOM tree, then Sax parse the XML file, deleting nodes from DOM as you get to the end tags in SAX. At the end if the DOM is empty then input had minimum structure. Just an idea - it's an interesting problem you have

Comment: Looking at answer below, if minimim structure is fixed and known then validate against schema would be simplest for sure, but if unknown until runtime then you need an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an XSD to define the structure of the XML and check the XML file against it.
You may take a look into javax.xml.validation.Validator;

Information for the validator:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html

example xsd
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/visualstudio/xml-tools/sample-xsd-file-purchase-order-schema?view=vs-2019

Simple XSD for you:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" name="B"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="C">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" name="E"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" name="F"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you see, i defined the hierachry for the elements. An XSD will ignore the order of B, C and F.
Furthermore you may define `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`, the default is 1.

Comment: Thanks, I never used validators, so can you tell me if those also support parameters checking? I mean, other than check if there is an XML element, also check if it has a certain parameter and, in case, compare/retrieve its value?

Comment: You can do that by defining <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" default="EN"/> in which case the element has to have the string-attribute "lang". If it is not set, it will be set to the defined default. If you want a specific value you may use fixed instead of default. <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" fixed="EN"/> That requires the attribute to be equal to the given value. For required attributes insert use="required". For further infos you may check out the [W3C Recommendation on xsd](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAttribute_Declarations)

Answer (score 2):

Your possible approach (transforming the two XML and comparing nodes) is good, but you don't compare paths, you compare nodes in parallel as you navigate the nodes.

As you stated, this assumes that names are unique.

E.g. like this, using recursive method:

```
public static void checkXml(String templateXml, String dataXml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Element templateRoot = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(templateXml))).getDocumentElement();
    Element dataRoot = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(dataXml))).getDocumentElement();
    if (! templateRoot.getNodeName().equals(dataRoot.getNodeName()))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different root elements: " + dataRoot.getNodeName() +
                                                                " != " + templateRoot.getNodeName());
    checkChildren(templateRoot, dataRoot, dataRoot.getNodeName());
}
private static void checkChildren(Node templateParent, Node dataParent, String parentPath) {
    for (Node templateChild = templateParent.getFirstChild(); templateChild != null; templateChild = templateChild.getNextSibling()) {
        if (templateChild.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String childPath = parentPath + "/" + templateChild.getNodeName();
            Node dataChild = getChild(dataParent, templateChild.getNodeName());
            if (dataChild == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing child: " + childPath);
            checkChildren(templateChild, dataChild, childPath);
        }
    }
}
private static Node getChild(Node parent, String name) {
    for (Node child = parent.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling())
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.getNodeName().equals(name))
            return child;
    return null;
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String template = "<A><B/><C><E></E></C></A>";
    String xml1 = "<A><B/><C><D></D><E/></C><F/></A>"; //Compliant to Template: the structure is kept
    String xml2 = "<A><B><E/></B><C/></A>"; //Not compliant to Template: E is child of B here, while E is child of C in Template
    String xml3 = "<A><C><E/><D/></C><F></F><B/></A>"; //Compliant to Template: the order of children doesn't matter

    test(template, xml1);
    test(template, xml2);
    test(template, xml3);
}
private static void test(String templateXml, String dataXml) throws Exception {
    try {
        checkXml(templateXml, dataXml);
        System.out.println("Ok");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Ok
Missing child: A/C/E
Ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Andreas' answer is nice - I slept on the problem and came up with a DOM/SAX approach, which I'll describe just for interest.

- Parse the minimum structure into a DOM tree (as in Andreas' solution)
- SAX Parse the input file as follows:
- On each start tag push the complete tag path onto a Stack (derive it by peeking at the top of the stack and appending the new tag - the Stack can contain a list of tags, or a concatenated String)
- On each end tag, pop the top from the Stack, look for a matching node in the DOM tree (that's a little bit fiddly as Document doesn't have a 'get by path' method). If you find one and it has NO children, then remove it from the tree, otherwise do nothing and carry on
- After SAX Parsing the whole input, if the DOM tree is empty the input was fine. Whatever structure remains in the DOM tree is the missing part of the input.

Downside is that you have manipulated the DOM for the minimum structure so you'd have to re-parse it every time, a bit of extra cost if you were processing a large number of input files.

Anyway, Andreas has pulled together a complete coded solution, so I'm only putting this up here as an alternative for general interest.

Comment: Note that this approach doesn't require unique names, if that did turn out to be an issue for you

Comment: This solution requires unique names too, since it won't correctly detect missing nodes otherwise.

Comment: You may be right, though when we say non-unique names do we mean for example several sibling E nodes within a single C, or E nodes scattered around the tree? For the latter both solutions would work as the paths are unique. For the former, if the minimum structure requires 3 C nodes and input has 2 then we'd get /C/E pushed onto stack and popped again twice in a row. If each time we find the first /C/E  in the tree and delete it then we'd be left with a single /C/E at the end. Hence I think it would work, but I haven't coded it to check

Comment: (and just logged off from work so stepping away from the laptop for a bit now :-) )

Comment: What if template requires three P nodes, with an A in the first, a B in the second, and a C in the third? If the document has three P nodes but A, B, and C are all in the third, the reported missing nodes will be incorrect.